# Did Stack Overflow come into being by commitment on a proposal in Area51?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

If yes, then when was Stack Overflow proposed on Area51? And who proposed it? I think it is the most active site in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User (collectively "The Trilogy") were the first three sites in the StackExchange Network and came before Area51. Once The Trilogy was successful (and after a brief foray into a paid SaaS model) we created Area 51 to democratically determine the subjects for the next Q&A sites to add to the network.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow is the most active site by far - see https://stackexchange.com/sites for detail:

- Stack Overflow 2.3 million questions
- Super User 103 thousand questions
- Server Fault 98 thousand questions

Stack Overflow was [announced in April '08](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/introducing-stackoverflow-com.html) and [began in July '08](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4). Area 51 [began June '10](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/).

So to answer your headline quetion - **No**.